# How to show that $\text{tr}\left(A^T B\right) \le \|A\|_{op} \|B\|_1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices. How can I prove that
$$ \text{tr}\left(A^T B\right) \le \|A\|_{op} \|B\|_1$$

where $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ is the largest singular value of $A$, and $\|B\|_1$ is the sum of all singular values of $B$? I can see this is true if $A=B$ by using SVD, but don't know how to prove this more general statement.

Comment: The trace of $A^T B$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of $A^T B$ which is less than or equal to the sum of the singular values of $A^T B$. Can you show that the $i$th singular value of $A^T B$ is less than or equal to the largest singular value of $A$ times the $i$th singular value of $B$?

Comment: @Eric I don't know how to show that...

Comment: This can be easily proved by using the characterisation that $\|B\|_1=\max_{Q^TQ=I}\operatorname{tr}(BQ)$.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably $A$ and $B$ are real. By padding them with zeroes, we may assume that they are square matrices. Let $A=USV^T$ be a singular value decomposition and let $D$ be any orthogonal diagonal matrix (i.e. a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $\pm1$) such that $U^TBVD$ has a nonnegative diagonal. Then
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)
&=\operatorname{tr}(VSU^TB)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(SU^TBV)\\
&\le\operatorname{tr}(SU^TBVD)\\
&\le\sigma_1(S)\operatorname{tr}(U^TBVD)\\
&=\sigma_1(S)\operatorname{tr}(BVDU^T)\\
&\le\sigma_1(S)\max_{Q^TQ=I}\operatorname{tr}(BQ)\\
&=\sigma_1(S)\|B\|_1.\\
\end{aligned}
The inequality in question also follows directly from **von Neumann's trace inequality** $\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)\le\sum_i\sigma_i(A)\sigma_i(B)$:
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)
\le\sum_i\sigma_i(A)\sigma_i(B)
\le\sigma_1(A)\sum_i\sigma_i(B)
=\sigma_1(A)\|B\|_1.
$$